# How to catch exceptions in youtube-dl python

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I am developing a project , where youtube-dl is used for downloading stuff from youtube & soundcloud.

When i try to download youtube videos, sometimes youtube-dl raises one of exception such as"Unsupported URL"," No video formats found" and many more.

I looked their documentation for those exceptions, but nothing helped me.

My code right now: (This doesn't catch any exceptions raised by youtube-dl).

I have tried with Exception class as well, but for some case that just dont work.

`code`

```
ydl_opts = {
'format': 'worstaudio/worst',
'postprocessors': [{'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
           'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
           'preferredquality': '192'}],
'outtmpl': 'media/'+result,
'quiet': False,
'noplaylist':True,
'ignoreerrors':True,
'max-downloads':1,
}
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)
title=(ydl.extract_info(query,download=False))['title']
title=re.sub('[\W_]+', '', str(title))+".mp3"
try:
    ydl.download([query])
except  youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError:
    print('Something went wrong!')
```

`code`

My question is how do i cover all possible exceptions in youtube-dl?.
(When ever exception is raised, i will return a JsonResponse() to display on front end)

Please help me

Comment: if you want to catch all exceptions during the process why just not use `except Exception as e` and then just print(e) ?

Comment: @LinhNguyen have tried with "Exception" but, for some cases it's not working.